# Need to connect machines from Perl script via SSH1 and SSH2

Tags: perl, ssh, openssh

I need to connect machines from Perl script via SSH1 and SSH2.

i am not able to find any package which works for both SSH1 and SSH2.

The following packages i have tried:

1. Net::SSH::Perl --- Works for SSH1 but not for SSH2.
2. Net::OpenSSH --- Works for SSH2 but not for SSH1.
3. Net::SSH2 --- Works for SSH2 but not for SSH1.

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Net::SSH::Any can use Net::SSH2 or Net::OpenSSH and the [development version](https://github.com/salva/p5-Net-SSH-Any) from GitHub provides the `SSH_Cmd` back-end that can be used to connect to hosts supporting only version 1 of the SSH protocol.

The `SSH_Cmd` backend uses the system `ssh` binary.